# How to add one JsonDocument to another in ArduinoJson

Tags: programming, json

I'm utilizing this json library: https://arduinojson.org/

I am attempting to write a function that creates a response object, and wraps an already built json document:

```
    void sendResponse(
            ResponseType state,
            JsonDocument *response
    ) {
        DynamicJsonDocument doc(256);

        doc[F("state")] = responseTypeFromEnum(state);
        doc[F("response")] = response; //breaks; how to do?

        this->sendJson(&doc);
    }
```

This fails of course, and I don't see a great solution anywhere...

I know I could use `createNestedObject()`, but this seems to require re-creating the given json object by hand? This would be a sub-optimal case.

Is there a way to easily wrap an existing JsonDocument in another?

Looking to take

```
{
  "some": "other document"
}
```

And wrap it like

```
{
  "state":"OK"
  "response": {
    "some": "other document"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [`JsonDocument`](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/jsondocument/) inside another one, but you must pass the document by value, not by pointer.
Since you receive a pointer, you need to dereference it before trying to assign:

```cpp
doc[F("response")] = *response;
```

**Node 1**: you could avoid this problem by passing `response` by reference, like so:

```cpp
void sendResponse(ResponseType state, const JsonDocument &response) {
  DynamicJsonDocument doc(256);

  doc[F("state")] = responseTypeFromEnum(state);
  doc[F("response")] = response;

  this->sendJson(doc);
}
```

**Node 2**: calling the assignment operator (`=`) causes a deep copy of the `response` document. You could avoid this copy by calling [`shallowCopy()`](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/jsonvariant/shallowcopy/) instead:

```cpp
doc[F("response")].shallowCopy(response);
```

**Node 3**: unfortunately [`shallowCopy()`](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/jsonvariant/shallowcopy/) is unavailable on ArduinoJson 7.

Comment: Interesting on Node 3.. Looks like `shallowCopy()` only came out in 6, so why is it gone in 7? Is there no equivalent there?

Looks like I'm currently using 6 though, compiles fine for me. Thanks for the point

Comment: Sorry, "Node" was supposed to be "Note" :-) Indeed, I removed `shallowCopy()` because `JsonDocument` doesn't store pointers to variants anymore. Instead, it stores indexes relative to the current document. It would be possible to recreate `shallowCopy()` but it would require extra plumbing (so extra weight), and I don't think it's worth it.

Comment: Thanks for the note!

I might personally argue that some extra code plumbing is worth a potentially large amount of end RAM usage savings to support :) (assuming it's not astronomically hard to do so)

Comment: Right, but on the other hand, it's not that difficult to avoid this situation. See the [the upgrade guide](https://arduinojson.org/v7/how-to/upgrade-from-v6/) for an example.